# What is the shortest read length achievable using Oxford Nanopore sequencers?

Tags: dna-sequencing

Is there a lower limit, in terms of read length, one could expect from sequencing DNA on Oxford Nanopore devices?

Comment: It depends on the size of the DNA fragments you are sequencing. They use 400bp amplicon libraries for their SARS-COV-2 sequencing protocol, which is about the shortest library prep I've seen for Nanopore. If your DNA is highly fragmented, you can probably expect a lot of reads around the 500 bp range or smaller.

Comment: I've had fragments come out in the low 10's of  bases - using non-standard protocols in a non-standard way, where you can see read through of both adapters.

Comment: @bob1 low 10’s including the adaptors?

Comment: Do you know if it is mentioned in the manual or in the sequencers specs or else? I would love to have a reference.

Comment: @alec_djinn no, actual sequence. In that case the adapters were (IIRC) about 50-80 bp each, though I would need to re-visit the sequences to confirm. I guess that total sequence length of ~150 bp as minimal. Though that would be the ones that passed QC, I haven't looked at the ones that didn't.